# Disable Caching for specific queries - Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

Can i Disable Solr Cache for specific queries?. I know Solr provides a way to disable caching on Filter queries but is there any way to disable document and query result cache?

Comment: Why would you want to disable caches? The way Solr works, if the data in the cache is no longer valid, then it is automatically purged. I don't see the benefit of disabling the document or query result cache.

Comment: @nikhil500 but Solr seems didn't know the data has been updated immediately, according to my testing result, it would take some time to refresh the data

Answer (score -2):

See here:
[enter link description here](http://solr.pl/en/2012/03/05/use-of-cachefalse-and-cost-parameters/)

Parameter cache=false
Setting the cache parameter to false we tell Solr not to cache current query results. This parameter can also be used as a filter query (fq) attribute, which tell Solr not to cache filter query results. What do we get from such behavior ? Let’s imagine the following filter as a part of the query:

```
fq={!frange l=10 u=100}log(sum(sqrt(popularity),100))
```

If we know that the queries with filter like the above one are rare, we can decide not to cache them and not change cache state for irrelevant data. To do that we add the cache=false attribute in the following way:

```
fq={!frange l=10 u=100 cache=false}log(sum(sqrt(popularity),100)
```

also if you need to do it as permanent you can uncomment cache fields from solrconfig.xml ( for example filterCache )